# Error while testing AWS API Gateway end point

Tags: curl, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I built a Lambda application and an API gateway with a GET method to fetch data from a dynamo db table based on the input email address. I am using token based authentication on my API. I tested the API using the API console and it works as expected. I am trying to test the end point using CURL through my MAC terminal. However I get the error:
*XXX is not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'Bearer XXX*
Below is the curl command I am using.

```
curl -X GET 'https://r8g1l8we5i.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod?email=user@example.com' --H 'Authorization: Bearer XXX'
```

Can you please advise what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks! I saw the question you linked, it doesn't seem to be the same issue. In my case, I am not using any variables, just directly running the curl on my terminal still getting the error